# where to save ASA sharing pin files

Tags: azure-spatial-anchors

I have followed this ASA tutorial, however one thing is not very clear to me.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrlearning-asa-ch1

My application can already create / share and find anchors, and I have changed it so it can use multiple anchors however it is not very clear to me where the files are supposed to be stored.

I would be under the impression that the demo was using the azure API or something but it just shows this url:

```
http://167.99.111.15:8090/file-uploads/static/file.
```

This appears just to be somekind of demo url, and then classes provided in the demo have functionality for creating/sharing/finding anchors but there is no get function?

So my question is are we supposed to set up our own file server to save and get these files? I was under the impression this would work through azure.

I have cannibalized most of the demo code into my own AnchorManager script, however there appear to be two demo's the one I linked and also this github repo.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-spatial-anchors-samples

Too much code to show here: https://pastebin.com/z5Pq94h2
The functionality for getting a shared anchor is supposed to be at line 379.

My expected result was a 200, but this way it will obviously return a 404 as the file does not exist and I cannot upload it.

Answer (score 0):

Alright i figured it out through this tutorial link, however none of this is hinted at through the other example/tutorial.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spatial-anchors/tutorials/tutorial-share-anchors-across-devices?tabs=VS%2CAndroid

You are supposed to deploy the SharingService sample and the tutorial after that goes into persistency through azure cosmos db.